# Random without repeating vb.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, random, static

I am trying to make a little quiz program that randomize from an array of 20 questions to get 5 random questions without repeating any of them 
I've searched and found that i need to use "**Static**" but it didn't Work
I also tried **System.Random()**
but it always repeat the same questions
I also need an initial question on the form load and the others when the submit button is clicked so they can't overlap too
any help ?

Comment: Rather than leave us to guess whats wrong why not post your code so we can tell you whats wrong?  We cant see your screen from here.  Also picking randomly from a list wont mean none of them repeat

Comment: If your code doesn't work then your code is wrong. If we can't see your code then we can't see what's wrong it. As for how to avoid duplicates, the answer should be glaringly obvious. How do lotteries avoid picking duplicate numbers? They simply remove them from the pool after selection. Why should it be aby different in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want random numbers, but rather a range of numbers that are randomly ordered.

Assuming that your questions are simply stored in a String array, you can use LINQ's OrderBy to randomly order the numbers 1-20, and then get the first 5 numbers after the order has been randomized by using LINQ's Take.

Take a look at this example:

```
Dim indices() As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, questions.Length - 1).OrderBy(Function(i) r.Next()).Take(5).ToArray()
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C6Kj7K)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try to avoid duplicates but it didn't work 
this code is supposed to pick a random value from "pick" List and then remove that value from the list

```
Dim ind As New List(Of Integer)
 Dim pick As New List(Of Integer)

For j = 0 To 13
            pick.Add(j)
        Next
        Dim randomvalue As Random = New System.Random
        Randomize()
        For j = 0 To 6
            Dim val = randomvalue.Next(pick(pick.Count - 1))
            ind.Add(val)
            pick.Remove(val)
        Next
```